# Unary bitwise-or fold in bitset constructor

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates, fold

I'm trying to make a struct that encapsulates some information about functions. Included in it is a bitset representing certain true/false behaviors. I'm trying to fold a parameter pack into the constructor of the bitset, but it fails.

Here is my code:

```
template<uint8_t ID_in, uint8_t...categories_in>
struct Function_Data {

    static constexpr const uint8_t ID = ID_in;

    // only two categories so far
    static constexpr const bitset<2> categories(categories_in|...);

    constexpr inline explicit Function_Data() {}
};
```

I expect the parsing of `categories(categories_in|...)` to understand that I'm trying to use a fold operation, but I get the error `‘categories_in’ is not a type` and then `expected ',' or '...' before '|'` token.

Trying the line `categories(...|categories_in)` yields different but similar messages of the form "was expecting X instead of Y".

Using static cast to unsigned long long int (for the constructor parameter type) results in `expected identifier before static cast`, which feels weird since there's a name right before.

Any help getting the struct to work would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need extra parenthesis for [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold):

```
static constexpr const bitset<2> categories{(categories_in|...)};
```

And as you are in class definition, use `{}` (or `= bitset<2>((categories_in|...))`) instead of `()` to construct members.

Comment: Dang, I tried parenthesis in the original `()`, but never in `{}`. So should I never use `()` in this circumstance? If so, why?

Comment: An explanation would be appreciated?

Comment: @Arkadiy the syntax is like this, it is said on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold)

Comment: @AnthonyMonterrosa You can only default-initialize members using `=` or `{}`. This is by design to distinguish with member-function declaration (to avoid confusion and likely help compilers).